# Intellij-idea Debugger disconnected when debugging maven test

Tags: maven, junit, intellij-idea

I have followed this link to debug maven test via Intellij Idea : http://www.grygoriy.com/2012/01/how-to-debug-tests-maven-test-via.html

When reaching the third step and starting debugging, It's connected but quickly disconnected and isn't stopped in breakpoints. I had in Intellij :

Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:5005', transport: 'socket'

Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:5005', transport: 'socket'

Any idea ?

Comment: Do your tests start successfully ? If it not reaching any breakpoint, it's maybe because your code isn't run.

Comment: @Guillaume Darmont I run code with "mvn test -Dmaven.surefire.debug", when reaching tests, I have in command line : 
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005

So I start debugging with I idea and it's quickly disconnected and command line remains in "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005"

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that prevents Idea from debugging Maven's goals is **forking**.

Plugins such **surefire** and **spring-boot** are using **forking** by default.

So, when you start debuging maven goal from IDEA it connects to maven, but process that you are really want to debug distincts from maven process, so it doesn't connected.

To prevent such behavior in surefire plugin you should read this article: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

In short:

If you use old surefire:

```
<configuration>
    <forkMode>never</forkMode>
</configuration>
```

In new surefire:

```
<configuration>
    <forkCount>0</forkCount>
</configuration>
```

But it's not much clear:

1. in case of CI (i wish you are using CI tools) you are not have prevent forking while it's much slow
2. if you ship your project to others - they will not be happy if some of modules behave in not default way

So if you want to please CI, IDEA, co-developers and yourself you should provide more smart way to allow debugging you build.

My suggestion:

1. default behavior is **forked** because build process is very often thing, while debugging it - is exception
2. debugger behavior is isolated with simple to use "switch on"

My variant:

```
<properties>
    <test.forkCount>1</test.forkCount>
</properties>
<profiles>
      <profile>
            <id>debug</id>
             <properties>
                     <test.forkCount>0</test.forkCount>    
             </properties>
        </profile>
 </profiles>
 <build>
      <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <!-- surefire -->
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>${test.forkCount}</forkCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

So, in IDEA you just require to create named Run configuration with goal **test** and include **debug** to profile list.

But in other contexts - maven behaves still by default.

Where is addition profit - you can incapsulate whole debug behavior in single profile.

For example in my real project debug profile:

1. swith off forking on spring-boot:run
2. switch off JaCoCo coverage (it requires forking on surefire)
3. keep building Docker images locally but prevents pushing to registry
4. keep full packaging process but prevents publication to nexus
5. redirects SOAP UI functional tests to specital URL for local debugging
6. redirects DBCONFIG to docker-based Postgres that is "always empty"
7. downgrades loglevel for log4j to DEBUG

So if I use `mvn <any> -P debug` i'm sure that my environment and process is really **debug**

But if i ran `mvn deploy` on CI - i will get full stack of my building process.

Comment: adding the -DforkCount=0 worked for me using maven surefire debug `-Dmaven.surefire.debug -DforkCount=0`

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if e.g. the annotation `BeforeAll` is incorrectly used. IntelliJ swallows problem during the test initialization.

In my case the `BeforeAll` method was not static:

Incorrect:

```java
    @BeforeAll
    private void beforeAll() {
        }
```

It can also happen if the `BeforeAll` method is failing and the test is not started. Using `mvn verify` should print the error message in these cases.